# Multiprocessing new terminal window with python

Tags: python, terminal, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, gnome-terminal

I am working with multiprocessing and I want to ask if there is some option to create new process with new terminal window in Ubuntu
I have 3 processes starting simultaneously, but I want results from them in separated terminals for each
Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details, preferably including some of the code that you use to launch the processes.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Sadly there is no* way to do what you want within python, as python has no control over the terminal it is running in.

What I think you *want* though is to separate the messages from your different processes, so you can see what's going on.  What I sometimes do for this (in testing only!) is to have each process log to a different *file*, and then watch those three files in three terminal windows.  You can do this with `watch` or even a simple `while` loop in bash:

```sh
watch -n 3 "cat /my/output/file" # or:
while true; do cat /my/output/file; sleep 3; done
```

of course you can replace `cat` with something more useful, perhaps `tail`.  Or you can just open the output files in a text editor which has an auto-revert facility (e.g. Emacs with `M-x auto-revert-mode`). This does exactly the same thing internally---poll the file for changes and update if need be.

I also really suggest you use `logging` inside your code, and give each paralleled function it's own logger (with the name derived from the parameters of the function).  (This can be easier with a small *class* rather than a function).  That way later on you can send *all* your output to a file, and if something goes wrong you can easily find out which run failed and extract information from only that run (with grep!).  I use this approach in paralleled fuzzy matching code (actually for matching music libraries) and it's invaluable when you need to dig into how some strange result occurred.

---

*Okay, I'm sure there's some horrible way to control some particular terminal and output to it, but that's not what you meant.